# Calling php function in android adds blank record in mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have created android app for adding data to my local host server. The problem is every time I enter data and submit there is no error reported in android app. But the data added to the mysql database is blank in all fields. Does anyone know how to overcome the problem?

As a fellow coder has asked I have added the code

```
package localhost80.sample1; 
import android.content.Context; 
import android.os.AsyncTask; 
import android.widget.Toast; 
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse; 
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet; 
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient; 
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.InputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStream; 
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter; 
import java.net.HttpURLConnection; 
import java.net.MalformedURLException; 
import java.net.URI; 
import java.net.URL; 
import java.net.URLEncoder; 
public class serverLinking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{ 
   private String link; 
   private Context context; 
   private String ed,lno,par,pcs,mts,wt,ct,var,gw,fw,remarks,method; 

   public serverLinking(Context context) 
    { 
        this.context = context; 
    } 

   protected void onPreExecute() 
    { 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
    } 
@Override 
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
    { 
        method = arg0[11]; 
        link = "http://192.168.0.104/narmadaa_trial1/android/add.php";         
        if(method.equals("POST")) 
        { 
            ed = arg0[0]; 
            lno = arg0[1]; 
            par = arg0[2]; 
            pcs = arg0[3]; 
            mts = arg0[4]; 
            wt = arg0[5]; 
            ct = arg0[6]; 
            var = arg0[7]; 
            gw = arg0[8]; 
            fw = arg0[9]; 
            remarks = arg0[10]; 

            try 
            { 
                URL url = new URL(link); 
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method);    
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8")); 
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("ed","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("lno","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("par","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode("pcs","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("mts","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("wt","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode("ct","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("var","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("gw","UTF-8")+"="+ URLEncoder.encode("fw","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode("remarks","UTF-8"); 
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush(); 
                bufferedWriter.close(); 
                os.close(); 
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close(); 
                return "Data Added Successfully"; 
        } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace();
     } 
    catch (IOException e)
    { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
   } 
  return null; 
} 

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    { 
        Toast.makeText(context,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) 
    { 
        super.onProgressUpdate(values); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: check your data at android side . is it empty ?

Comment: You need to show us your code. You don't expect a car mechanic to be able to fix your car without letting him/her see it, do you?

Comment: no code no help. All we can do here is imagine.

Comment: Please format your code. Having all code in one line makes it pretty unreadable. We're all glad to help, but don't make us work for it.

Comment: I used mobile app for adding that code. If you have used the android app you would have understood that uploading codes from mobile is pretty tedious. And thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
package localhost80.sample1;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
public class serverLinking extends AsyncTask < String, Void, String > {
    private String link;
    private Context context;
    private String ed, lno, par, pcs, mts, wt, ct,
    var, gw, fw, remarks, method;
    public serverLinking(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override protected String doInBackground(String...arg0) {
        method = arg0[11];
        link = "http://192.168.0.104/narmadaa_trial1/android/add.php";
        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            ed = arg0[0];
            lno = arg0[1];
            par = arg0[2];
            pcs = arg0[3];
            mts = arg0[4];
            wt = arg0[5];
            ct = arg0[6];
            var = arg0[7];
            gw = arg0[8];
            fw = arg0[9];
            remarks = arg0[10];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("ed", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("lno", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("par", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("pcs", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("mts", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("wt", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("ct", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("var", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("gw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("fw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("remarks", "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                return "Data Added Successfully";
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void...values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

check your querystring(String data).
passing parameter need that's name.
and separator is &

value1=value2=value3.... (x)

value1name=value1&value2name=value2&value3name=value3... (o)

**EXAMPLE**

```
String data = "ed=" + ed
            + "&lno=" + lno
            + "&par=" + par
            + ....
```

check received data($_GET or $_REQUEST) on add.php

Comment: How would making the columns nullable stop the fields from being blank? How do you know that this is a db issue at all? As far as we know, the OP might just be sending blank values to the PHP to start with. There's far from enough info about the issue for it to be answered.

Comment: sorry, i was hasty

Comment: Kim so you mean like I have to add the variable value after that = sign. Am I right?

Comment: Thanks Kim. It was made possible just because of your kind help

Comment: as i see your code, you passed values without it's name.and chained with '='. so your add.php will not recognize any value. i added some example for you.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and everything went just fine

Comment: congratulation :)

Answer (score 0):

Many Thanks to @Meow Kim for the valuable suggestion. I have rounded and found the conclusion for the problem and it was just the missing sign in post request that made the terrible problem.
And also thanks to @Magnus Eriksson for constantly coming up with a suggestion to aid me. So the final code for the above mentioned is as follows.

AddEntry.java (Just renamed Sample1.java Main Activity file for easy identity)

```
package am.dx.narmadaa.addentry;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class addEntry extends AppCompatActivity {

public EditText Eed, Elno, Epar, Epcs, Emts, Ewt, Ect, Egw, Efw, Erem;
public Spinner Evar;
public String str_ed, str_lno, str_par, str_pcs, str_mts, str_wt, str_ct, str_var, str_gw, str_fw, str_rem, str_var_code;
public Button Add, Clr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_entry);
    addInput();
}

public void addInput() {
    Eed = findViewById(R.id.ed);
    Elno = findViewById(R.id.lno);
    Epar = findViewById(R.id.par);
    Epcs = findViewById(R.id.pcs);
    Emts = findViewById(R.id.mts);
    Ewt = findViewById(R.id.wt);
    Ect = findViewById(R.id.ct);
    Egw = findViewById(R.id.gw);
    Efw = findViewById(R.id.fw);
    Erem = findViewById(R.id.rem);
    Evar = findViewById(R.id.var);
    Add = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    Clr = findViewById(R.id.btnClr);

    Add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            str_ed = (Eed.getText()).toString();
            str_lno = (Elno.getText()).toString();
            str_par = (Epar.getText()).toString();
            str_pcs = (Epcs.getText()).toString();
            str_mts = (Emts.getText()).toString();
            str_wt = (Ewt.getText()).toString();
            str_ct = (Ect.getText()).toString();
            str_gw = (Egw.getText()).toString();
            str_fw = (Efw.getText()).toString();
            str_rem = (Erem.getText()).toString();
            str_var = (Evar.getSelectedItem()).toString();

            switch (Evar.getSelectedItemPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    str_var_code = "fw";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    str_var_code = "brw";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    str_var_code = "mw";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    str_var_code = "bw";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    str_var_code = "ow";
                    break;
            }
            displayToast(str_ed, str_lno, str_par, str_pcs, str_mts, str_wt, str_ct, str_var, str_gw, str_fw, str_rem);
            serverLinking hostlink = new serverLinking(addEntry.this);
            hostlink.execute(str_ed, str_lno, str_par, str_pcs, str_mts, str_wt, str_ct, str_var_code, str_gw, str_fw, str_rem, "POST");
        }
    });

    Clr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Eed.setText("");
            Elno.setText("");
            Epar.setText("");
            Epcs.setText("");
            Emts.setText("");
            Ewt.setText("");
            Ect.setText("");
            Egw.setText("");
            Efw.setText("");
            Erem.setText("");
            Evar.setSelection(0);
        }
    });
}

private void displayToast(String d_ed, String d_lno, String d_par, String d_pcs, String d_mts, String d_wt, String d_ct, String d_var, String d_gw, String d_fw, String d_rem) {
    Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    String toasttext;
    toasttext = "Entry date : " + d_ed + "\nLot no : " + d_lno + "\nParty : " + d_par + "\nTotal Pcs : " + d_pcs + "\nTotal mtrs : " + d_mts + "\nTotal Weight : " + d_wt + "\nCount : " + d_ct + "\nVariety : " + d_var + "\nGray Width : " + d_gw + "\nFinishing Width : " + d_fw + "\nRemarks : " + d_rem;
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.START, 0, 0);
    Toast.makeText(addEntry.this, toasttext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

ServerLinking.java (Connector file for server)

```
package am.dx.narmadaa.addentry;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class serverLinking extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
private String link;
private Context context;
private String error;
private String ed, lno, par, pcs, mts, wt, ct, var, gw, fw, remarks, method;

public serverLinking(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    method = arg0[11];
    link = "http://192.168.0.101/android/add.php";

    if (method.equals("POST")) {
        ed = arg0[0];
        lno = arg0[1];
        par = arg0[2];
        pcs = arg0[3];
        mts = arg0[4];
        wt = arg0[5];
        ct = arg0[6];
        var = arg0[7];
        gw = arg0[8];
        fw = arg0[9];
        remarks = arg0[10];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(method);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("ed", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ed, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("lno", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lno, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("par", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(par, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("pcs", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pcs, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("mts", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mts, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("wt", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(wt, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("ct", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ct, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("var", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(var, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("gw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(gw, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("fw", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(fw, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("remarks", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(remarks, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            os.close();

            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();
            return "Data Added Successfully";
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = e.toString();
        }
    }
    return "Data Addition Failed\n Error Details : " + error;
}

//    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Toast.makeText(context, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Android Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="am.dx.narmadaa.addentry">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".addEntry">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

android/add.php

```html
php server file
<?php
     include '../database.php';

     $ed = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "ed",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     if(strlen($ed)==8)
     {
     $d = substr($ed, 0, 2);
     $m = substr($ed,2,2);
     $y = substr($ed, 4, 4);
}
if(strlen($ed)==6)
{
$d = substr($ed, 0, 2);
$m = substr($ed,2,2);
$y = "20".substr($ed, 4, 2);
}
if(strlen($ed)==4)
{
    $d = substr($ed, 0, 2);
    $m = substr($ed, 2, 2);
    $y = date("Y");
}
 else 
{
$d = "00";
$m = "00";
$y = "0000";
}

$newed = implode("-", array($y,$m,$d));
$lno = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "lno",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$par = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "par",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pcs = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "pcs",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$mts = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "mts",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$wt = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "wt",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$ct = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "ct",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$var = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "var",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$gw = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gw",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$fw = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "fw",FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$remarks = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "remarks",FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo $newed."<br/>".$lno."<br/>".$par."<br/>".$pcs."<br/>".$mts."<br/>".$wt."<br/>".$ct."<br/>".$var."<br/>".$gw."<br/>".$fw."<br/>".$remarks;

$sqlInsertAndroid = "INSERT INTO lems(ed,lno,par,pcs,mts,wt,ct,var,gw,fw,remarks,sluo) VALUES('".$newed."','".$lno."','".$par."','".$pcs."','".$mts."','".$wt."','".$ct."','".$var."','".$gw."','".$fw."','".$remarks."',now())";
echo "<br/>".$sqlInsertAndroid;
$dataInsertAndroid = mysqli_query($dbconn, $sqlInsertAndroid);
?>
```